# Cannot assign types to a React High Order Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, high-order-component

I need to create a HOC that takes a component and returns a new one that takes flattened props (I'am using [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) to make it happen) and applies the unflattened props to the original component.

The HOC without types looks like this (I have tested it and it's working as expected):

```
const HOC = (Component) => (props) => {
    const newProps = unflatten(props);

    return <Component {...newProps} />;
};
```

The problem is that now I need to add types to it so this is what I think should work:

```
const HOC = (Component: React.ComponentType) => (props: { [key: string]: string; }) => {
    const newProps = unflatten(props);

    return <Component {...newProps} />;
};
```

This solution is causing this error on the final return line

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
const newProps = unflatten(props) as { [key: string]: string; };
```

or

```
const newProps = unflatten(props) as  any;
```

Comment: Combining this typing and your suggestion made it work :)
type IProps = { [key: string]: string; };
type IHOC = (Component: React.ComponentType<IProps>) => (props: IProps) => JSX.Element;